# Verification of ring isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've to verify that $E(\mathbb{Z})$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are isomorphic. $E$ is defined as
$$E(\mathbb{Z}) = \{f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} | f(x+y) = f(x) +f(y)\}$$

This means there exists a function $\phi$ such that
$\phi(f+g) = \phi(f) + \phi(g)$
and
$\phi(fg) = \phi(f)\phi(g)$
with $\phi(x) \in \mathbb{Z}$

This comes as end chapter verification exercise of rings and rings' isomorphism. Groups and homorphisms are not introduced yet. So I Couldn't simply devise an ad-hoc isomorphism for the task. With your suggestion that $f: ℤ → ℤ$ is a group homorphism and to pick $f(n) = nf(1)$, for all $n ∈ ℤ$, it is straightforward. I developed like this:

Let $f+g$ defined as $f(n)+g(n) = n(f(1) + g(1)) so φ(n(f(1) + g(1))) = f(1) + g(1);$

Let $f∘g$ defiend as $f∘g = f((g(n))) = n⋅g(1)⋅f(1), φ(f((g(n)))) = g(1)⋅f(1)$, thus $\phi$ is indeed a ring isomorphism.

I'm not sure if the notation $φ(n(f(1) + g(1)))$ is correct.

Comment: Indeed, that is **part** of what you need to do. You also need $\phi$ to be a bijection. But you aren’t asking us to verify your work, as your subject line suggests. So... any ideas of what $\phi$ might be?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ is a groupe homorphism then for all $n\in\mathbb{Z},f(n)=nf(1)$ thus $f$ is entirely determined  by the value of $f(1)$. Let $\phi:f\rightarrow f(1)$ then because of what said above $\phi$ is injective, it is also surjective because for all $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, $\phi(n\rightarrow na)=a$. I let you verify that $\phi$ is a ring homorphism.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The question boils down to figuring out what exactly the $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ group homomorphisms are.

> They are all determined by their value at $1$.